# global $post inside plugin query messes up every new post page in wp-admin

Tags: php, plugin-development, errors, globals

I have a very strange problem that I am trying to troubleshoot:

I have a query (to build an array) that I run on a custom post type inside my plugin. It looks like this:

```
function makePointerQuery(){
//global $post; 
$pqargs = array(
    'post_type' => 'sbap_pointer',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
    );
$pointer_query = array();
$pp_query = get_posts($pqargs);
if ($pp_query) :
foreach ( $pp_query as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );
       $pointer_query[] = array(
            'id'       => get_post_meta($post->ID, '_sbap_pointerid_text', true ),
            'screen'   => get_post_meta($post->ID, '_sbap_screen_text', true ),
            'title'    => get_the_title($post->ID),
            'content'  => get_the_content($post->ID)

        );
endforeach; endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
return $pointer_query;
}
```

If I leave out global $post, my plugin seems to function just fine, but I get the following PHP Notice (with debugging on):

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /wp-includes/post-template.php on line 289
```

BUT if I include global $post, while that notice goes away, something very strange happens. Every ("Add New") new post page ("post-new.php" in posts, pages, my custom post type, etc) is pulling up and filling out the data from my first custom post (ie the title, content, slug are all filled in with that post's data instead of the blank fields as would be normal for a new post).

I am at a loss as to how to eliminate that error notice while still having my plugin function as expected (without messing up every new post in admin).

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems in your code.

1. You use `$post` as a iteration variable which is an habit best avoided
2. You use `setuppostdata` which changes the global `$post` without you using any function that actually needs it

your loop should look like

```
foreach ( $pp_query as $p) : 
       $pointer_query[] = array(
            'id'       => get_post_meta($p->ID, '_sbap_pointerid_text', true ),
            'screen'   => get_post_meta($p->ID, '_sbap_screen_text', true ),
            'title'    => get_the_title($p->ID),
            'content'  => get_the_content($p->ID)

        );
endforeach; endif;
```

then the `reset_post_data` is unneeded as well

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I had already tried something similar, and using this I still get the PHP notice above about trying to get the property of a non-object.

Comment: Well, here is something very strange: As I said, with the technique above I was STILL getting the PHP notice. So I started looking line by line to see if any of them could be written differently, and simply by replacing "get_the_content($p->ID)" with "$p->post_content", the problem went away!. I will mark your answer as the solution since it led me to that anyway, thanks.

Comment: Probably the reason is that `get_the_content` expects totally different parameters, and for it you actually do need the global $post to be set, but the way you ended up doing it is better IMO